# Oracle Apex 20 - Gantt how hide inactive days and hours

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In the Oracle Apex 20 Gantt chart, I would like to display the tasks broken down by hours, working hours from Monday to Friday, from 6:00 to 18:00. I would like to hide Saturday and Sunday, as well as 0:00 to 06:00 and 18:00 to 24:00.
Is this possible?